# Ember data 1.0.0: confused with per-type adapters and serializers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am migrating from Ember data 0.13 to 1.0.0 beta.  According to the doc https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md, there are now per type adapters and per type serializers.

This means that I can no longer define a "myRestAdapter" with some specific overrides for the primary key and the authentication. I need to implement this code now for each model type resulting in duplicating xx times the same code.

Code in Ember data 0.13:

```
App.AuthenticatedRestAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({  

  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function() {
      return '_id';
    }
  }),

  ajax: function (url, type, hash) {
    hash = hash || {};
    hash.headers = hash.headers || {};
    hash.headers['Authorization'] = App.Store.authToken;
    return this._super(url, type, hash);
  }
});
```

Code in Ember data 1.0.0 (only for setting the primary key to _id instead of _id:

```
App.AuthorSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

  normalize: function (type, property, hash) {
    // property will be "post" for the post and "comments" for the
    // comments (the name in the payload)

    // normalize the `_id`
    var json = { id: hash._id };
    delete hash._id;

    // normalize the underscored properties
    for (var prop in hash) {
      json[prop.camelize()] = hash[prop];
    }

    // delegate to any type-specific normalizations
    return this._super(type, property, json);
  }

});
```

Have I understood it correct that I need to copy this same block now for every model that requires the _id as primary key ?  Is there no longer a way to specify this once for the whole application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the code seams to be `type` agnostic, why you don't just create your custom serializer that your models can extend from, something like:

```
App.Serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

  normalize: function (type, hash, property) {
    // property will be "post" for the post and "comments" for the
    // comments (the name in the payload)

    // normalize the `_id`
    var json = { id: hash._id };
    delete hash._id;

    // normalize the underscored properties
    for (var prop in hash) {
      json[prop.camelize()] = hash[prop];
    }

    // delegate to any type-specific normalizations
    return this._super(type, json, property);
  }

});
```

And then use `App.Serializer` for all your models:

```
App.AuthorSerializer = App.Serializer.extend();
App.PostSerializer = App.Serializer.extend();
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Do models that don't have pertype adapters/serializers defined still fallback to a default adapter/serializer?

Comment: @MehulKar I have not found a possibility to fallback to a default adapter.

Comment: @intuitivepixel I think you may have hash and property mixed up.

Comment: @intuitivepixel The normalize method should be function(type, hash, property) not function (type, property, hash) as per the Transition.md from Ember Data 1.0 Beta.

Comment: @alvincrespo, yes! thank you for the hint, corrected my answer.

Comment: @intuitivepixel and what is the way to serialize the data back to its original format so that it is in the format the server is expecting. My server expects the variables to be underscored. Please any help on this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can also set `App.ApplicationSerializer`. This will work if you want this normalization applied to *every* model.

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function (type, property, hash) {
    var json = { id: hash._id };
    // ...
    return this._super(type, property, json);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know if this is recommended, but since I need the primary key to be "_id" for every model, I just did this:

```
DS.JSONSerializer.reopen({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work with primary key ids of _id:

```
MediaUi.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

  normalize: function (type, property, hash) {
    // property will be "post" for the post and "comments" for the
    // comments (the name in the payload)

    // normalize the `_id`
    var json = { id: hash._id };
    delete hash._id;

    // normalize the underscored properties
    for (var prop in property) {
      json[prop.camelize()] = property[prop];
    }

    // delegate to any type-specific normalizations
    return this._super(type, json, hash);
  }

});
```

The difference here is that I'm switching hash in the for loop to `property` and passing in `hash` into the super. Maybe this is a bug with Ember Data 1.0 Beta?

Comment: I had to do the switch because hash is actually a string of the type of data, in my case `hash` was returning "movie" - which is the model I'm working with.

Comment: My bad. I was going off of @intuitivepixel example. But the transition.md on the ember data repo has the right order.