# Ember data 1.0 Application -en AdapterSerializer not working?

Tags: serialization, ember.js, adapter

My question is in line with this one: [Ember data 1.0.0: confused with per-type adapters and serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561009/ember-data-1-0-0-confused-with-per-type-adapters-and-serializers)

Problem is that I cannot initialize RESTSerializer per type because I need to set **ActiveModelSerializer** :

```
App.FooSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({attrs: {}});
```

to set relationships as embedded.

**So I want to set 1 serializer for all models.** I tried to set `ApplicationSerializer`, but this did not call any hooks when getting response from server (And I'm sure my server gives correct response):

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
        return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
    },
    extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
        return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
    },
    normalize: function(type, property, hash) {
        return this._super(type, property, hash);
    }
});
```

Setting my adapter doesn't seem to work:

```
var adapter = require('init/adapter');

    App.ApplicationAdapter = adapter.extend({
        defaultSerializer: myAdapter //I QUESS THIS IS WRONG?
    });
```

Did I make a syntax error? Any other suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I found my mistake but not a great solution. Seems that my FooSerializer overrides the general ApplicationSerializer..

Is there a way where I can set both? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use both per say, but you can have your `FooSerializer` extend your `ApplicationSerializer` and then override the methods that you'd like to use differently.

```
App.FooSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend({
   extractArray: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    // alert each record to annoy the user
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
   },
});
```